# Golang Https both server and client show error "connection reset by peer"

Tags: go, ssl, https

**Answer**:

The "reset by peer" is caused by censorship. I deployed another server, it works at first but after a while the "reset by peer"
happens again.

So if anyone get into this that both client and server show "reset by peer", please check if the server and dns were deployed in a censored country。

**The original question:**

I wrote a simple file server using GoLang, everything works fine when testing on localhost. But when testing on remote sever with curl, both client and server shows "connection reset by peer".

The code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./media")))
    e := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "/root/my.cer", "/root/my.key", nil)
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

The server shows error:

> TLS handshake error from **my_ip**:26637: read tcp 10.0.4.12:443->**my_ip**:26637: read: connection reset by peer

The curl client shows:

> curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to my_server.com:443

And there is only a ClientHello and a ServerHello in Wireshark
[image]

Then I tried visit in browser, there is only a ClientHello, no ServerHello, same error on server side.

How to trace this? My environment: Linux + GoLang 1.17.1, all operation done using root account, can't be file permission problem.

Comment: How did you generate cert and key?

Comment: @Clemens the cert and key was generated from the site "ohttps.com", the cert is bound to my domain name. I tried visit by Ip address directly in browser, it shows warning like "not secure", if I click "ignore and continue", my site shows correctly.

Comment: I'd suggest trying again with a cert and key generated with openssl or the generate_cert.go tool from the go repo https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go , you can also try adding the GODEBUG=http2debug=2 environment variable when running your application and if that does not show anything, you'd have to resort to a debugger like delve to see what's going on.

Comment: I'd also update to the current Go version 1.18 to see if it behaves the same.

Comment: @Clemens I did update to latest 1.18, same problem.